# Removing a Backbone View without actually deleting the root el it was attached to

Tags: backbone.js

Is there a way to remove a view without deleting the root el element?

---

If I have a div in a parent view like this:

```
<div class="child-view" />
```

And I render a new View with an el like below

```
el : '.child-view'
```

It will attach to the view as expected but when removing the view

```
this.childView.remove();
```

`<div class="child-view" />` is removed from the parent, if I want to initialize the view again I have to manually append the div again which is annoying

```
this.$el.append('<div class="child-view" />');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to override the remove method like this :

```
remove: function() {
    this.$el.empty();
    this.undelegateEvents();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this instead :

```
this.undelegateEvents();
this.$el.empty()
```

Comment: @Rohit - your edit should have been a comment on this answer not an edit.

Comment: (True, I was actually sitting beside @anurag_29 on this when I made the edit.) this.$el.remove() should be this.$el.empty()